# Unable to run Jmeter (database test) script using gradle

Tags: jmeter, performance

I am unable to run jmeter JMX file using gradle task 'jmeterRun' which is having test for database checkpoint. I am getting error message

`"Could not return Connection java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found" in the jmeter.log file.`

Here is my JDBC Connection Configuration:
[image]

Here is build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'jmeter'
 apply plugin: 'java'

  dependencies {
 testRuntime "com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.3"
 }

 buildscript {      

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.2-2.9"
        //classpath "com.github.kulya:jmeter-gradle-plugin:1.3.4-2.13"
        classpath "kg.apc:jmeter-plugins:1.1.3"
        classpath "kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-standard:1.1.3"
        classpath "kg.apc:jmeter-plugins-extras:1.1.3"
    }
}

jmeterRun.configure {
jmeterTestFiles = [file("src/test/resources/Zone_RR_CRUD.jmx")]
jmeterPropertyFile = file("src/test/resources/jmeter.properties")
}
```

**Jmeter.log**

`2015/08/17 12:05:05 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement: Could not return Connection java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@coredb-useast1c01-02.qa.ultradns.net:2115:CUE1C2Q
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.JdbcConnectionFactory.newInstance(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:182)
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.InstrumentedResourceLimitingPool.newPoolable(InstrumentedResourceLimitingPool.java:655)
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.newPoolable(ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.java:145)
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcConnectionPool.newPoolable(ResourceLimitingJdbcConnectionPool.java:91)
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.InstrumentedResourceLimitingPool.get(InstrumentedResourceLimitingPool.java:371)
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.pool.ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.get(ValidatedResourceLimitingPool.java:97)
    at org.apache.avalon.excalibur.datasource.ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.getConnection(ResourceLimitingJdbcDataSource.java:188)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement$DataSourceComponentImpl.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:286)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement.getConnection(DataSourceElement.java:146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler.sample(JDBCSampler.java:85)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`

The same thing is working fine when I placed `ojdbc6.jar` into `jmeter/lib` folder on my local machine.

I have no idea how it will work when I run through gradle task i,e. jmeterRun.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please look into it

Comment: Have you tried the same with newest version 1.3.4 of plugin?

Answer (score 1):

This error is generally observed when JDBC driver is missing.
**No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@coredb-useast1c01-02.qa.ultradns.net:2115:CUE1C2Q**
Can you try placing driver jar in JMeter lib folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JDBC driver classpath to the dependencies pulled from the repo. The problem is that your JMeter build from Maven is missing the JDBC driver, pulling it in via Maven should fix that.